# How can I limit pick a question from a list only once in a random order?

Tags: python, list, tkinter, random

I am trying to modify my flashcard python script. It works fine, but what I am triying to do is to modify the random function so that a single question (and its answer) it is not chosen twice. The script should not continue picking questions after the list is completed. I would also need to add a button that let me brwose back to previuos selections.

Any suggestions?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from random import randint

root = Tk()
root.title('Domande')
root.geometry("850x400")
root.resizable(True, True)

words = [
    (("Stadio Olimpico"), ("ROMA")),
    (("Stadio Artemio Franchi"), ("FIORENTINA")),
    (("Stadio Armando Picchi"), ("LIVORNO")),
    (("Stadio Luigi Ferraris"), ("SAMPDORIA"))
    (("Stadio Arechi"), ("SALERNITANA"))
]

# get a count of our wods list
count = len(words)

def next():
    global hinter, hint_count
    #Clear screen
    answer_label.config(text="")
    label.config(text="")
    hint_label.config(text="")
    #Reset Hint stuff
    hinter = ""
    hint_count = 0

    #Create random selection
    global random_domande
    random_domande = randint(0, count-1)
    #Update label with Domande
    domande.config(text=words[random_domande][0])


#Keep track of the hint
hinter = ""
hint_count = 0

def hint():
    global hint_count
    global hinter

    if hint_count < len(words[random_domande][1]):
        hinter = hinter + words[random_domande][1][hint_count]
        hint_label.config(text=hinter)
        hint_count +=1

#Define function to hide the widget
def hide_widget(widget):
    widget.pack_forget()
    widget.config(text=words[random_domande][1])

#Define a function to show the widget
def show_widget(widget):
    widget.pack()
    widget.config(text=words[random_domande][1])

#Labels
domande = Label(root, text="", font=("Times", 14))
domande.pack(side=TOP)

#Create an Label Widget
label = Label(root, text="", font=("Times", 14))
label.pack()

#Create Buttons
button_frame = Frame(root)
button_frame.pack()

hint_button = Button(button_frame, text="Hint", command=hint)
hint_button.pack()

button_show = Button(root, text= "Show", command= lambda:show_widget(label))
button_show.pack()

#Create a button Widget
button_hide = Button(root, text= "Hide", command=lambda:hide_widget(label))
button_hide.pack()

next_button = Button(button_frame, text="Next", command=next)
next_button.pack()

#Create Hint Label
hint_label = Label(root, text="")
hint_label.pack()

answer_label = Label(root, text="", font=("Times", 14))
answer_label.pack(side=BOTTOM)
#Run next function when the program starts
next()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You can use `random.choice()` and append to another list and when checking the next check if not in the other list and if is loop again and try choosing again (or maybe .choice picks only once that I don't remember)

Comment: A suggestion to get more/better replies to your questions: Try to remove all the code that is irrelevant to your actual question. This makes it easier to understand your issue without having to read through many (for the issue at hand) irrelevant lines of code.

Comment: `random.shuffle(words)` will give you a random permutation of the `words` array.

Comment: Hi guys. Unfortunatelly for me, I am still stuck at the same point. Could you give me any more specific hints? Would you be so kind to write down the part of the code I might need?

Comment: @acw1668. Sorry about that.